# In jekyll, how to parse a variable as markdown instead of printing it as is?

Tags: jekyll

Given the following file:

```
_data
  slides.yml
```

which includes

```
- title: Slide one
  desc: |
    welcome to the slideshow
    This is an open-source slideshow, built with [deck.js](https://github.com/imakewebthings/deck.js), GitHub and [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com).

- title: Slide two
  desc: |
    Second slide with bullet points
     * Hello world
     * This is a slideshow
```

In my index.html I have

```
{% for slide in site.data.slides %}
  <section class="slide">
    <h2>{{ slide.title }}</h2>
    {{ slide.desc }}
  </section>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I get Jekyll to interpret {{ slide.desc }} as markdown? Does something like this exist:

```
...
{{ slide.desc AS markdown }}
...
```

Thanks!

Albert

Answer (score 18):

Found the answer!

```
...
{{ slide.desc | markdownify }}
...
```

[Here is the reference](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/).

Comment: Awesome. Just came across this post and this will be handy to know!